# Open subsets of a subspace in $\Bbb R$ with the upper limit topology.

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to answer a question related to topologies in the real numbers.

Say I have two different topologies in $\Bbb R$, for example the standard and lower limit topologies. I know that a set $A$ can be open in $\Bbb R$ with both of these topologies, but I've been told that the conditions for openness are different.

For example, say $X = (0,1)$. People tell me that $A$ is open in $\Bbb R$ with the standard topology simply by looking at the definition of a topology in the real numbers. I feel like that "just look at it" approach only work for the standard topology.

**Looking at an example:**

Say I have $A = [-1, 1)$ with the subspace topology inherited from $\Bbb R$ with the upper limit topology.

If $B$ is a subset of $A$, how do I figure out if $B$ is open in $A$? How do I figure out if $B$ is even open in $\Bbb R$ in the first place? What does openness look like in the upper limit topology?

1. $B = [0,1)$ -> I have been told that $B$ is open in $\Bbb R$ because $B = [-1, 1) \cap [0, \infty)$ and the latter set is open in $\Bbb R$. This doesn't resolve the underlying issue of *why* a set $[a,b)$ is open in $\Bbb R$, let alone in $A$.
2. $B = (-1,0]$ -> Same issue as for 1.
3. $B = (-1,0)$ -> My thoughts here are *if $X$ from above is open in $\Bbb R$ for the reasons discussed, then $B$ must also be open in $\Bbb R$.* The complement of $B$ in $A$ is $[-1, -1]\cup [0,1)$. This brings me to the exact same problem as 1.
4. $B = [-1,0]$ -> If the idea that a set like $X$ is open in $\Bbb R$ using the definition of a topology holds here, then $B$ is similarly closed. We can also say that by inspecting the complement of $B$, we have no open intervals $O$ in which $B = A \cap O$. Hence it must not be open in $A$.

For 1. and 2., no matter how I tackle them, I run into the problem of needing to know that some set - $A$, $B$, a complement, etc. - is open in $\Bbb R$ with the upper limit topology.

Any suggestions would be excellent.

Comment: Are you mixing up the lower and upper limit topologies?  The $B$ you gave is not open in $\mathbb{R}$ with the upper limit topology.  Did you mean to say that $B$ is open in $A$?  (And also, $[0,\infty)$ is not open in $\mathbb{R}$ in the upper limit topology.  It is in the lower limit topology, hence my first question.)

Comment: This pretty much sums up what I don't understand. You say $B$ is not open in $\Bbb R$ with the upper limit topology. Is this for the first $B$ given? It could be that I was told incorrectly. I don't know that it's open. I'm trying to figure out if it is.

Comment: The first $B$:  $[0,1)$ is not open in the upper limit topology.

Comment: There is an alternate criterion for open-ness in $\mathbb{R}_u$ that is nice.  A set $U$ in $\mathbb{R}_u$ is open if and only if for each $x \in U$ there is $\delta > 0$ such that $(x-\delta, x] \subseteq U$.